# Java OutOfMemory during sorting

Tags: java, sorting, exception, out-of-memory

I have a task about building a pyramid using list of numbers, but there is one problem with one test. In my task I need to sort a list. I use Collections.sort():

```
Collections.sort(inputNumbers, (o1, o2) -> {
            if (o1 != null && o2 != null) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            } else {
                throw new CannotBuildPyramidException("Unable to build a pyramid");
            }
        });
```

But this test fails

```
@Test(expected = CannotBuildPyramidException.class)
    public void buildPyramid8() {
        // given
            List<Integer> input = Collections.nCopies(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1, 0);

        // run
        int[][] pyramid = pyramidBuilder.buildPyramid(input);

        // assert (exception)
    }
```

with OutOfMemoryError instead of my own CannotBuildPyramidException(it will be thrown in another method after sorting). I understand that it is because of TimSort in Collections.sort() method. I tried to use HeapSort, but I couldn`t even swap elements because my input list was initialized as Arrays.asList() and when I use set() method I get UnsupportedOperationException. Then I tried to convert my list to common ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(inputNumbers);
```

but I got OutOfMemoryError again. It`s not allowed to edit tests. I dont know what to do with this problem. Im using Java8 and IntelliJIdea SDK

Comment: Maybe catch the OutOfmemoryError and throw your own Exception?

Comment: @Adder it is a bad Java practice to catch `Error`s. `Error` is throws when JVM is unable to process further with program execution and, by definition, cannot be handled correctly.

Comment: Allocate more heap?

Comment: May I suggest the point of this test might be to check that the list is sorted in-place and never copied? Can you ask your teacher about this test?

Comment: @kutschkem This could be the thing, right. But if it's true, then... we're discriminating students that have less than 16 GB of memory? It could be done in a different way, eg. by forcing students to run JVM with `-XMx=64m` and reducing list size to 10 million elements, or something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the list created by `Collections.nCopies(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1, 0)` uses a **tiny** amount of memory and is **immutable**. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,T)) says *"Returns an immutable list consisting of n copies of the specified object. The newly allocated data object is tiny (it contains a single reference to the data object)"*. And if you look at [the implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk13/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#L5025), you'll see it does exactly what one would expect from that description. It returns a `List` object that only **pretends** to be large, only holding the size and the element **once** and returning that element when asked about any index.

The problem with `Collections.sort` is then two-fold:

- The list must not be immutable, but that list is. That btw also explains the `UnsupportedOperationException` you got when you tried to `set()`.
- For performance reasons, it [*"obtains an array containing all elements in this list, sorts the array, [and writes back to the list]"*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)). So at this point the tiny pretend-list does get blown up and causes your memory problem.

So you need to find some other way to sort. One that works in-place and doesn't swap anything for this input (which is correct, as the list is already sorted). You could for example use bubble sort, which takes O(n) time and O(1) space on this input and doesn't attempt any swaps here.

Btw, about getting the memory problem *"because of TimSort"*: Timsort is really not to blame. You don't even get to the Timsort part, as it's the preparatory copy-to-array that causes the memory problem. And furthermore, Timsort is smart and would detect that the data is already sorted and then wouldn't do anything. So if you actually did get to the Timsort part, or if you could directly apply it to the list, Timsort wouldn't cause a problem.

Answer (score 2):

This list is too huge! `Collections.nCopies(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1, 0);` gives us list of 2^31-1 elements (2147483647), each one taking about 4 bytes in memory (this is "simplified" size of `Integer`). If we multiply it, we'll have about 8.59 GB of memory required to store all those numbers. Are you sure you have enough memory to store it?

I believe this test is written in a very bad manner - one should never try to create such huge `List`.

Comment: No, I have no enough memory

Comment: Is it ok to send this task with one failed test and to hope that my teacher has enough memory? :)

Comment: @PashaMinigun We can't tell you what your teacher will be okay with.  I suggest contacting your teacher before the assignment is due to ask him about this issue.

Comment: If you're certain that's the amount of data you need to use then perhaps you need to increase the maximum heap that java is running with? You can do this with argument '-Xmx'

Comment: Hmm I think the test makes somewhat sense if the assumption is that one List can fit in memory, but not two. So making sure everything is done in-place. That's a little too many assumptions IMO, but maybe that's the point of the test?

Comment: Doesn't the test expect an CannotBuildPyramidException?

Comment: I think you're wrong about the size. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,T)) says *"Returns an immutable list consisting of n copies of the specified object. The newly allocated data object is **tiny** (it contains a single reference to the data object)."*

Comment: If you look at [the implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk13/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#L5025), you'll see it does exactly what one would expect from that description. It returns a `List` object that only **pretends** to be large.